# Why i can't assign value to a variable on data() from the mounted lifecycle hook in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For example, when i try `console.log(this.products)`, the console returns a empty array. But the products was populate with a fetch on the created lifecycle. Or when i try to assign value to the variable items.

```
created() {
        fetch("https://cardapio-digital-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products")
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.products = data
                this.productsByCategory = this.products
            })

        console.log(this.products)
        this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
    }
```

Comment: _"Or when i try to assign value to the variable items."_  not sure what you're saying here

Comment: Note that you are not saving the values from `return response.jsonn()` anywhere.   
Try this:   

```.then(response => {
     this.products =  response.json()
     console.log(this.products)
 })```

Comment: @ViniciusKammradt OP is doing it correctly. The code in your comment won't work since `response.json()` returns a promise